# How to override system fonts in OS X?

Tags: macos

I want to override a system font in my Mac OS X app with a slightly different variant of my new font. Let's take `Georgia` as an example.
I have a another `Georgia.ttf`, which is a different version of `Georgia` available on my Mac. I bundled this `ttf` with my app using:

```xml
<key>ATSApplicationFontsPath</key>
<string>fonts</string>
```

I copied my version of `Georgia` into `Resources/fonts`. But when I try to use the font `Georgia`, the font that gets applied is still the system version of `Georgia`. So I removed Georgia from my Mac and then ran my application again. This time, my version of Georgia got loaded and rendered correctly.

I guessed that the problem occurs because both the fonts have the same [internal] name: `Georgia`. So I changed the font name of my `Georgia.ttf` to be `MyGeorgia` using [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/). Now, I tried to load the font `MyGeorgia` and it works perfectly.

Now, my question is, how can I override the system `Georgia` with my `Georgia`, without having to rename my version into something else that is not already present on my Mac?

Comment: Isn't there a `<` too many in your source?

Comment: Yes, removed it. But that's not what's causing my issue.